# Error while running parallel make

Tags: linux, compilation, makefile, gnu-make

Consider following make:

```
all: a b

a:
        echo a
        exit 1


b:
        echo b start
        sleep 1
        echo b end
```

While running it as `make -j2` I receive the following output:

```
echo a
echo b start
a
exit 1
b start
sleep 1
make: *** [a] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
echo b end
b end
```

We have quite a  big make file and it's easy to miss error, since there's no error message at the end of execution.

Is there a way for error message to appear also just in the **end** of the make execution?

UPDATE:

See my possible [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999800/wrapping-gnu-makefile-with-another-makefile/11028784#11028784) how to check make exit status from within make.

Comment: I always pipe the output of Make through a script which highlights lines with keywords such as "error" and "warning".

Comment: @OliCharlesworth We also use colorgcc, which highlights gcc warnings/errors, but compilation is too long and there's still high chance error will be missed by a programmer.

Comment: In that case... Well, I don't know how to solve your problem directly, but one possibility is to wrap Make in a script that `tee`s its output to a temporary file, and then greps that file for relevant messages and dumps it at the end.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth We have quite a big set of makefiles the best is to relay on exis statuses than on error messages. Errors can be different quite different - error from gcc, sed, ls, mkdir, proprietary scripts etc. Wrapping could be a solution, since out most make returns correct exit status. But the question is if there are standard solution or I miss something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If any program called by `make` returns with an error, the return code of `make` will not be zero. So after calling `make` you could just check the return code to see if an error occurred. On `bash` (and many other shells like `zsh`) you could do the following:

```
# make
....
# echo $?
```

The echo will print `0` if anything was ok and will print something else if it wasn't.

You could also run the check from inside a shell script:

```
make
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Everything OK"
else
    echo "Something went wrong!"
fi
```

If you need the exact error message the easiest way is to redirect the output from `make` to some file and `grep` for the error if execution failed.

But the way I usually do this is to run `make` in parallel and re-execute it with `-j1` if something went wrong so I will get a clean error message. I guess this could be put into a shell script using the technique above.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is that the output of both these tasks are independent. So, if you're running 5 tasks in parallel, and 3 of them gave errors, they may very well be interspersed by output of the other tasks.

The best thing to do is run a set of serial tasks together, send their error output into a file... and print it to screen when exiting.

P.S. - Also, never use exit 1 in a task unless there absolutely is an error!