# Wrapping GNU makefile with another makefile

Tags: linux, compilation, makefile, gnu-make

This is following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971615/error-while-runing-parallel-make).

I have `Makefile.real` (`Makefile` from prev [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971615/error-while-runing-parallel-make)):

```
all: a b

a:
        echo a
        exit 1


b:
        echo b start
        sleep 1
        echo b end
```

Now I want to create `Makefile` that is simple wrap of `Makefile.real`:

- It calls `make` with `Makefile.real` with the same args as it was called
- It should print error message id `Makefile.real` fails
  **This is my goal** - print error message in the end of parallel make
  (see [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971615/error-while-runing-parallel-make))

Therefore following commands should terminate with error message:

```
make -j1 a b (1)
make -j2 a b (2)
```

I suspect `Makefile` should be something close to:

```
%:
      $(MAKE) -f Makefile.real $(MAKECMDGOALS); \
      res=$$?; if [ $$res != 0 ]; then echo "Failed!!!"; fi; exit $$res
```

The problem is that target '%' will be called twice for `a` and `b` for (2).

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered `include Makefile.real`?

Comment: @Beta Don't see how it solves my problem - what I try to overcome is that in case of parallel compilation there's no error message in the end of make. Question edited

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution I ended with

```
ifneq ($(REAL_MAKE),1)
# run_make will be called once (it's .PHONY target), 
# even if make is called with several targets
%: run_make
        @:

.PHONY: run_make
run_make:
        $(MAKE) $(MAKECMDGOALS) REAL_MAKE=1; \
        if [ $$? -ne 0 ]; then               \
            echo "*** Error ***" >&2;        \
            exit 1;                          \
        fi

else  # REAL_MAKE defined (actual makefile)

### HERE comes original make we want to wrap ###

endif  # # REAL_MAKE defined (actual makefile)
```